# Simulate Right CTRL key using xdotool inside Virtual box

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, xdotool

I'm running Virtualbox in my Windows 10. I have a virtual machine running Raspbian.

Inside Raspbian virtual machine, i'm using xdotool.

From Raspbian, using xdotool, can i simulate to press Right Ctrl that it is my host key in VirtualBox so i can change the size of my VirtualBox-window?.

I mean from Raspbian that it is a virtual machine from VirtualBox, can i execute "Host + A"?.
As Host is right CTRL key, i tried this two things but it only execute normal ctrl key inside Raspbian.

```
xdotool key ctrl+a
```

and i tried

```
xdotool key 'Control_R'+a
```

But it executes inside raspbian a normal ctrl+a and it selects all the files inside a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it from inside the virtualized environment.  You would have to automate that action from outside Raspbian, with an app that runs natively on Windows, such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).  Very similar idea, but scripts are worded a bit differently.

```
Send, ^a
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s3